# Consultar dados em três tabelas onde apenas duas são relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde, vou tentar explicar uma situação em que estou, tenho 3 tabelas(A,B,C) onde A e B estão relacionadas diretamente, B e C também estão relacionadas. Preciso pegar o valor de um campo na tabela C onde estou consultado dados na tabela A.
Tentei fazer da seguinte forma porém o resultado veio null:

```
SELECT h.Id, h.TagHistorian, h.Descricao, um.Sigla ,h.ComentarioHistoria,
   (SELECT plc.TipoVariavel_Id FROM plc WHERE h.Id = plc.Id) AS varplc
FROM historian h
INNER JOIN um ON um.Id = h.UM_Id
INNER JOIN tipovariavel tp ON tp.Id = h.TipoVariavel_Id
```

Abaixa a estrutura das tabelas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente preciso pegar a descrição do "TipoVariavel" sendo que a consulta será na tabela "Historian" que está relacionada com a tabela "PLC".

Comment: Talvez tenha sido apenas um erro de transcrição mas, de acordo com sua figura, a tabela HISTORIAN não contém um campo TipoVariavel_Id (existe na tabela PLC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que quer e não tem como saber muito bem sem os valores.

Para relacionar seriam `JOINS`:

```
SELECT A.X, A.Y, B.X, B.Y, C.X, C.Y
FROM TAB_A A
LEFT JOIN TAB_B B ON B.PK = A.FK_B
LEFT JOIN TAB_C C ON C.PK = B.FK_C
```

Para "buscar valor relativo" poderia ser `sub-querie`:

```
SELECT A.X, A.Y, B.X, B.Y, 
(SELECT C.PK FROM TAB_C C WHERE C.PK = B.FK_C LIMIT 1 ORDER BY data DESC)
FROM TAB_A A
LEFT JOIN TAB_B B ON B.PK = A.FK_B
```

No caso acima, caso houver mais registros na relação TAB_B e TAB_C, usei o `LIMIT 1 ORDER BY data DESC` para trazer por exemplo, um valor de última data.

Use o `LEFT` em seu `JOIN` para trazer tudo, assim você verifica como está a relação, e o `LIMIT` para trazer somente 1 valor, mas geralmente ele acusa erro na querie.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, basicamente quero buscar a Descrição na tabela "TipoVariavel" que está relacionada com "PLC", nesta consulta preciso dos dados da tabela "Historian" da tabela "PLC" e da descricação da variável que está na tabela "TipoVariavel".